# Difference of using transfer vs _transfer in OpenZeppelin (same for dash functions)

Tags: openzeppelin, openzeppelin-contracts

In openzeppelin contracts in same cases we have 2 types of functions for the same functionality, one of them preceded by a dash symbol (_). That is the case of transfer(x, y, z)/_transfer(x, y, z) function.

I am aware that when I want to modify the behaviour if I inherit the function, I should use _transfer(x, y, z).

But what's the real difference? Because it happens in lot of functions, and I'm not really sure if I should use transfer(x, y, z) or _transfer(x, y, z).

So then, if I'm not gonna modify its original behaviour, should I use transfer or _transfer?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for function `_transfer` is simply code-reuse.

It is called from both functions `transfer` and `transferFrom`.

It can also be called from functions `mint` and `burn`, if you need to implement them.

And when the exact same functionality is used in several places, it is beneficial to implement it in a single place rather than in several places, because:

1. It allows you to to fix/change/update the common functionality in a single place
2. The overall size of your executable (binary) code is subsequently smaller

Comment: So then, if I'm not gonna modify its original behaviour, should I use transfer or _transfer?Thanks

Comment: @AlexAcc: What do you mean "use"? From other contracts (as well as from the off-chain), you cannot "use" `_transfer` since it's internal. So define "use" please.

Comment: Ok sorry, I didn't get the point that _transfer is internal (for only to use inside the contract). So if I need to make a transfer inside of the contract logic I should use _transfer, and if I need to invoke a transfer outside the contract I'd use transfer. Right?

Comment: @AlexAcc: Outside - `transfer` of course. Inside - depending on your exact purpose, but most likely `_transfer`.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine, you have a frontend for your smart contract. From frontend, you cannot call `_mint` or `_approve`. They are internal. They can be can be called inside the functions of your smart contracts.

example.sol:

```
    function mintTokens() external {
        _mint(msg.sender, 10*10**18);
    }
```

index.html:

```
await window.contract.methods.mintTokens().send({from: account});
```

From index.html `mintTokens()` is called, not `_mint`